# pip install requierements.txt in azure app service

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I want to launch a web app on Azure app sevice connected to my azure repo, but I have this problem

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/bin/python /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp34ji_cp4 Check the logs for full command output.

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
"2022-03-25 07:00:00"|ERROR|Failed pip installation with exit code: 1

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:\n     command: /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/bin/python /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp34ji_cp4\n         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t7g41qou/pywinpty\n    

Complete output (6 lines):\n    \n    Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.\n    This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through\n    the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/\n    \n    Checking for Rust toolchain....
\n    ----------------------------------------\n
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/bin/python /tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp34ji_cp4 Check the logs for full command output.\nWARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/8da0e58792c9438/antenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.7 -i /tmp/8da0e58792c9438 --compress-destination-dir -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log
```

can anyone help me with this ?

I tried to add pip version in my requierments.txt but it doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the specific packages for windows and the compilation works.

As my current app service plan is on linux, the windows packages pyw32 could not work. so just by removing it from de requierement file the compliation works and my app is launched.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).